# How to use feynmf in LyX?

Tags: lyx, feynmf

LyX [documentation](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/FeynmanDiagrams) suggest to to use `feyn` package to draw Feynman Diagrams, It works fine, but unfortunately too restrictive and simple for my needs, I tried to use `feynmf` package instead, but it doesn't output anything, and I searched Internet for some possible examples/solution, but found none, are they compatible at first place? and if yes, can you please explain how to use it in LyX?

Comment: Ok, maybe at least somebody can advice how to build complex Feynman diagrams in LyX?

Comment: I have no idea about Fynman diagrams, but can you import a working latex document into LyX to give you a start?

Comment: Any solutions yet? I actually got it to work with LyX a couple years ago, but now those documents compile blank again, and I don't know what changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `feynmf`, you have to set up LyX to run `mf` (Metafont) in addition to `pdflatex`, on all the files generated by the `feynmffile` environments (as I understand it, having never used the package).

I don't actually know how to do that, but another option altogether that requires no such extra step is the `tikz-feynman` package. Add

```
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
```

to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, and you can write code such as

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
```

directly in an ERT, and get this:

[image]

#### Important note

`tikz-feynman` uses the graph drawing libraries of TikZ to place vertices automatically, but this only works when the PDF is generated with `luatex`. With `pdflatex`, which default in LyX, the above code will generate

[image: pdflatex output]

which is less nice.

So if you want this automatic layout, you must *PDF (LuaTeX)* as the output format, for example in Document --> Settings --> Format.

But you can also place things manually, and then `pdflatex` has no problems. To generate a diagram like the above, you can use the following code in an ERT.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [above left=of a] (i1);
    \vertex [below left=of a] (i2);
    \vertex [right=of a] (b);
    \vertex [above right=of b] (f1);
    \vertex [below right=of b] (f2);

    \diagram*{
      (i1) --[fermion] (a) --[fermion] (i2),
      (a) --[photon] (b),
      (f1) --[fermion] (b) --[fermion] (f2)
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

See the package manual for more information about its capabilities.

Example `.lyx` file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  a -- [photon] b,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

};
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{tikzpicture}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{feynman}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex (a);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex [above left=of a] (i1);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex [below left=of a] (i2);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex [right=of a] (b);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex [above right=of b] (f1);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
vertex [below right=of b] (f2);
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
diagram*{
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      (i1) --[fermion] (a) --[fermion] (i2),
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      (a) --[photon] (b),
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

      (f1) --[fermion] (b) --[fermion] (f2)
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

    };
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{feynman}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{tikzpicture}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```